# Can I load two versions of the same DLL in IronPython

Tags: .net, dll, clr, ironpython

I have a DLL which does both encryption and decryption, but at a client site the decryption is failing when a string is encrypted and then sent to another machine to be decrypted via a webservice.

Currently I've tested that the DLL on the destination machine can encrypt and decrypt a string just fine.  What I would like to do is take the DLLs from BOTH machines (which are at different versions), load them in an IronPython script, have one DLL encrypt and the other DLL decrypt.  I know that I can load them both into clr.References given they differ by version, but how do I differentiate between them after that?

Here's what I have right now using a single DLL:

```
from Some.Dll import SecurityUtils
from System.Text.Encoding import UTF8

import clr


class Codec:
def __init__(self, publicKey):
    self.decryptedBytes = None
    self.encryptedString = None
    self.publicKey = publicKey

def encrypt(self, text):
    #dir = os.path.dirname(__file__);
    #dir = os.path.join(dir, '..');
    #dir = os.path.join(dir, 'oldsystem');

    #dir = sys.path.append(dir)
    #clr.AddReference(r'Some.Dll')

    textBytes = UTF8.GetBytes(text)
    self.encryptedString = SecurityUtils.Encrypt_RSA(textBytes, self.publicKey)

def decrypt(self):
    self.decryptedBytes = SecurityUtils.Decrypt_RSA(self.encryptedString)

def getDecryptedString(self):
    return UTF8.GetString(self.decryptedBytes)
```